# How to convert bathtub drain to shower?

Tags: shower, drain, bathtub, pvc, slab

I have a 1960's house.  I am renovating a bathroom, removing bathtub and putting in  shower.  I will be using [Schluter Kerdi-Shower](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Schluter-Kerdi-Shower-38-in-x-60-in-Off-Center-Shower-Kit-with-PVC-Flange-KSK9651525SPVC/308315439) for conversion.

I would like to know what parts of that iron drain I need to replace with which PVC parts.

[image: Bathtub drain]

Comment: What does that red box say?  That one piece is probably the only one you will want to keep.

Comment: That piece is lose and turns.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what the best way to seal that pipe is, but that is going to be a part of your concern.

Comment: What is wrong with keeping the drain at the end? Isn't it a lot of trouble to relocate the drain to the center? When the drain is relocated is a new trap installed or does one run a pipe that goes to and feeds into the existing trap? Is it simply wise to redo the drains down to the lateral in case the original trap won't last the lifetime of the new shower?